# Shiny - not able to download a markdown output

Tags: r, download, shiny

I am really struggling to get this one down. I have searched here and all over but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I apologize as this maybe a really silly question.But I am a novice.
I have put in place a shiny application, where it renders an existing R markdown file which is compiled based on the Shiny inputs. In the end I get what is like a PDF file. Everything works fine except for the option to download. When I push the download, it just opens another webpage session from the beginning.
How can get the final document displayed as an PDF file downloaded. Really appreciate any help.

I edited this code based on a shiny example, but still cannot get to the bottom of this. When I click on the download button it opens another session.
Edited code

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  library(knitr)
  output$markdown <- renderUI({
  HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('RMarkdown_pdf1.Rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
  })
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },

    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd')

      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
      ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
})

library(shiny)
library(knitr)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Drift Report - Beta Version 1.0"),
    selectInput("n",
                "Number of files:",
                choices = c(1,2,3,4)),
    checkboxInput("d", label = "Data Summary", value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("k", label = "Drift Plots", value = FALSE),    
    radioButtons("p", label = "Plot Type", 
                       choices = list("Point Plot" = 1, "Cumm Plot"=2, "Both     - Side by Side"=3, "Both - One underneath the Other"=4),selected = NULL,inline=TRUE),
    sliderInput("s","No of Plots", min = 1, max = 50, value = 10, width =   "40%"),
    submitButton("Apply Changes"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.n == 1",
      fileInput("dat","File Upload for Analysis", accept = ".eff")
    ),
    radioButtons('format', 'Document format for Download', c('PDF', 'HTML',   'Word'),
                 inline = TRUE),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.n == 2",
      fileInput("dat","1st File Upload for Analysis"),
      fileInput("dat3","2nd File Upload for Analysis")
    ),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'),
    uiOutput('markdown')
  )
)
```

log

```
2016-04-26T18:50:56.177858+00:00 shinyapps[98254]: Warning in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
```

2016-04-26T18:50:56.177862+00:00 shinyapps[98254]:   cannot open file 'datEff.R': No such file or directory

2016-04-26T18:50:56.178919+00:00 shinyapps[98254]: Quitting from lines 10-45 (RMarkdown_pdf1.Rmd)

2016-04-26T18:50:56.180088+00:00 shinyapps[98254]:

2016-04-26T18:50:56.182026+00:00 shinyapps[98254]:   cannot open the connection

2016-04-26T18:50:56.182763+00:00 shinyapps[98254]: Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection

2

Answer (score 2):

The id of your download button is `downloadData` but in server code you used `downloadReport`. They don't match.

Comment: Thank you, that's so right. Now it does download but when trying to open, it can't as it says file maybe damaged or format not supported. I have a feeling that although I created this Rmd file on RStudio with the pdf option, it doesn't necessarily mean, the output post shiny is actually a pdf format. Am I supposed to do a knit2pdf? or any other suggestion?

Comment: I think this link will help you http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html

Comment: Hi, I checked the example and edit it. However now I get a message "cannot open the connection". When looking at the log file I can see that it is not finding some functions I have sourced within the markdown doc, although the shinyapps run just fine. I wonder if it has to do with that. My goal was just to get this final Rmarkdown output and save as it is. I am hopeless...

Comment: You new code works fine on my computer. Make sure that you have the `rmd` file in the same folder as the `ui.R` file, and check to make sure that file names match.

Comment: The apps work after I deploy it to shinyapps,io. But I am still getting the same error when trying to download it. Here is what I get from the log: see on top

Comment: That error seems to be related to a file `datEff.R` that you sourced in the rmd file. Make sure you put that file in the same folder as your rmd file, and try set a working directory before you source it if it still does not work.

Comment: They are all in the same folder, otherwise the apps would not work either. It's just the download is causing the problem, The rmd fie works perfectly under the shinyapps.

Comment: I think `      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))` is causing the problem. Right now it copies the rmd file to a temporary directory for processing to avoid possible permission issue. Either do not move them to temporary directory, or also copy the `datEff.R` file to that temporary folder.

Comment: thank you for the help. Now it works for HTML only using the following: `knit2html("RMarkdown_pdf1.Rmd",force_v1 = TRUE)`. Could not make it work for pdf though.